# mtr not working from cron

Tags: cron, trace

The script below works perfectly when ran from the CLI but when running it from a cron it fails with the error

```
"/usr/local/sbin/mtr: Failure to start mtr-packet: Invalid argument"
```

Here's the `cron` entry from root's own `crontab`:

```
* * * * * /root/trace_to_fpp.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

At first I thought it was a permissions issue but that does not seem to follow the error. Below is the script being used.

```
#! /bin/bash

DIR=/var/log/traces/FPP/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/$(date +"%H")/
DIR_FILE=$DIR$(date +"%M")
mkdir -p $DIR
/usr/local/sbin/mtr -o "L SRD NBAW JMXI" --report-wide --report-cycles 5 --no-dns --aslookup 1.1.1.1 > $DIR_FILE
/usr/local/sbin/mtr -o "L SRD NBAW JMXI" --report-wide --report-cycles 5 --aslookup 1.1.1.1 >> $DIR_FILE
```

This is on CentOS 6, if that's important.

Comment: What platform (UNIX flavour or Linux distribution) is this running on? Can't seem to reproduce it here.

Comment: @roaima CentOS6

Comment: [root@voipmonitor ~]# crontab -l | grep trace


    * * * * * /root/trace_to_fpp.sh   >/dev/null 2>&1

    [root@voipmonitor ~]#

Comment: How do you derive the error message if you discard all output from your cron job?

Comment: Why is `mtr` in `/usr/local/sbin`? There's an `mtr` package you can use under Cent6, and if you're using it, there's no reason for it to show up under `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 0):

Originally, I had received the same error as the OP.

Upon researching into this a bit more, I found that the script worked fine once PATH was defined so it could find `mtr` and `mtr-packet`.

I tested this on: `CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)`

It appears that cron is using a different PATH:

```
[root@graylog ~]# crontab -l |grep PATH
* * * * * /bin/echo $PATH >> /var/log/cron.log
[root@graylog ~]# tail -n1 /var/log/cron.log 
/usr/bin:/bin
```

We can work around this by defining a new path within the script.
Here is a look at the script which resides at `/etc/mtr-background.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin/"
DIR=/var/log/traces/$(/usr/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d)/$(/usr/bin/date +"%H")/
DIR_FILE=$DIR$(/usr/bin/date +"%M")
mkdir -p $DIR
/usr/sbin/mtr -o "L SRD NBAW JMXI" -w -e -c 60 -4 1.1.1.1 >> $DIR_FILE
```

Here is a look at relative crontab entry which was setup under the root user's account:

```
* * * * * /etc/mtr-background.sh >> /var/log/cron.log
```

I located the full PATH for `mtr` and `mtr-packet` by using `whereis` like so:

```
[root@graylog ~]# whereis mtr; whereis mtr-packet
mtr: /usr/sbin/mtr /usr/share/man/man8/mtr.8.gz
mtr-packet: /usr/sbin/mtr-packet /usr/share/man/man8/mtr-packet.8.gz
```

Thanks

Comment: Not relevant here because the error message the OP provided clearly shows the `mtr` program running and failing

Comment: @roaima:  I’m not understanding you.  Yes, the error message shows that the `mtr` program is running and failing.  Specifically, it is failing to start `mtr-packet`.  And `mtr` is running because the script invokes it with a full path (`/usr/local/sbin/mtr`).  So why do you say that an incomplete PATH can’t be the problem?

Comment: TimelesslyPrecise: We prefer answers that fit the question.  The question shows that `mtr` is in `/usr/local/sbin`, so why don’t you show  `/usr/local/sbin` in your answer?  Or am I misunderstanding your point?

Comment: The first sentence of your answer says that in your case you needed to adjust `$PATH` to find the tool. The OP has a completely different situation in that the tool is running but failing. Your answer isn't addressing the question that's actually been asked

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the feedback. Updated my answer to provide more details from my testing efforts.

Comment: This still brings up the fact that wherever your mtr is installed.. the binary itself is hard-coded to call mtr-packet and if wherever your mtr is installed to, if you dont have that path, mtr will fail with the OP's error. 

```$ rpm -ql mtr |grep bin
/usr/sbin/mtr
/usr/sbin/mtr-packet```